# Gatsby Create Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, gatsby, express-graphql

I am trying to create a gatsby site where I have projects posted, each with tags. I followed a basic tutorial on creating a gatsby blog, and am now working through gatsby's tags as documented on their website. Along the way while changing variable names from path to slug to avoid reserved words, I seem to have messed up because I can no longer create blogpost pages, nor tag pages. Each post is enclosed in a folder named by the post title, holding an index.md file defining its content, date, tag etc.

The following error is output when I try to run gatsby develop,

**ERROR #11323**

```
Your site's "gatsby-node.js" must set the page path when creating a page.

The page object passed to createPage:
{
    "slug": "/an-example-post",
    "component": "C:\\Users\\Monolith\\Documents\\programming\\webdev\\Gatsby-Portfolio\\src\\templates\\post.js",
    "context": {
        "slug": "/an-example-post"
    }
}
```

My gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
     const {createPage} = actions;

     const postTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/post.js');
     const tagTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/tags.js")
     //const postTemplate = require.resolve('src/templates/post.js');
     //const tagTemplate = require.resolve("src/templates/tags.js")
     
     return graphql(`{
        allMarkdownRemark{
            edges{
                node {
                    html
                    id
                    frontmatter{
                        slug
                        title
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        tagsGroup: allMarkdownRemark(limit: 2000) {
            group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
              fieldValue
            }
          }

    }`)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.errors){
            return Promise.reject(res.errors);
        }


        
        res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach( ({node}) => {
            createPage({
                slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
                component: postTemplate,
                context: {
                    slug:node.frontmatter.slug
                },
            })
        })

          // Extract tag data from query
        const tags = res.data.tagsGroup.group

        // Make tag pages
        tags.forEach(tag => {
            createPage({
                // path: `/tags/${_.kebabCase(tag.fieldValue)}/`,
                slug: `/tags/${(tag.fieldValue)}/`,
                component: tagTemplate,
                context: {
                    tag: tag.fieldValue,
                },
            })
        })

    }) 
}
```

As previously mentioned I was concerned the path variable being a reserved word could be an issue, but I got further using it than omitting it so for now it has stayed.

Example post.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default function Template({data}) {
    const {markdownRemark: post} = data;

    return(
        <Layout>
        <div>
            <h1 className="postTitle">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <div className="tagGroup">
                {post.frontmatter.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <h2 className = "tagStyle">{tag}</h2>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <p>{post.frontmatter.description}</p>
            <p>{post.frontmatter.date}</p>            
            {/* <h2 className="tagStyle">{post.frontmatter.tags + " "}</h2> */}
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.html}} />
        </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}


export const postQuery = graphql`
    #query BlogPostByPath($slug: String!) {
    query($slug: String!) {
        markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: {eq: $slug} }) {
            html
            frontmatter {
                slug
                title
                description
                date
                tags
            }
        }
    }
`
```

The tags.js is very similar to gatsby's default with slight alterations for content. Here is the Graphql query I am using.

```
Tags.propTypes = {
  pageContext: PropTypes.shape({
    tag: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMarkdownRemark: PropTypes.shape({
      totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      edges: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          node: PropTypes.shape({
            frontmatter: PropTypes.shape({
              title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
           //   slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
            fields: PropTypes.shape({
              slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
          }),
        }).isRequired
      ),
    }),
  }),
}

export default Tags

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($tag: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 2000
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: [$tag] } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
           fields {
             slug
           }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

If anyone has any information to help point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. I have been running through gatsby's documentation for hours and have yet to make substantial progress.

Comment: " createPage({
        // Path for this page — required
        path: " - not using 'path' variable doesn't mean it can'tt be used as prop name

Comment: hmm ok, so I changed my request to createPage({ path: node.frontmatter.slug, component: postTemplate, context: { slug:node.frontmatter.slug}. but the error message now shows the path and slug in context is null. Im not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `tag` in your context but expecting a `slug`:

```
    createPage({
        slug: `/tags/${(tag.fieldValue)}/`,
        component: tagTemplate,
        context: {
            tag: tag.fieldValue,
        },
    })
```

And:

```
   query($slug: String!) {}
```

The context is a way to pass data to your component template to use it to filter your data. Ideally should be a unique parameter (like a `slug`, `id`, etc). In that way, in your `gatsby-node.js` you should fetch all your posts, pass a unique field by context, and use that variable in your template to get all your needed data of each post.

In addition, you must provide a `path`, not a `slug` to your function.

You should change your `createPage` function to:

```
    createPage({
        path: `/tags/${tag.fieldValue}/`,
        component: tagTemplate,
        context: {
            slug: tag.fieldValue,
        },
    })
```

Keep in mind that `fieldValue` should be a slug (or kind of) despite having different naming.

I would recommmend reading Gatsby's tutorial: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-seven/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the thorough answer. I seem to have made a few things click with those changes and think that is definitely the solution to the issue. I also posted the wrong final code snippet for my tags.js. I believe this should be the query used to generate the tags but it fails to query field fields for MarkdownRemark, although allMarkdownRemark seems to be the main method suggested in the gatsbyjs tutorials.